# PHP - mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 on Windows Server 2016.
I have 2 SQL Server Instances: 
1. 10.201.74.50
    - Installed on the local Windows Server above.
    - @@VERSION: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4293802) - 13.0.5081.1 (X64)   Jul 20 2018 22:12:40   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
2. 10.3.3.192\SQLEXPRESS,1433
    - Installed on another Windows Server.
    - @@VERSION = Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86)   Dec 10 2010 10:56:29   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I can connect to the 2 SQL Server Instances by Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Command Prompt as picture below.
[image: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio]
[image: Command Prompt]

In case of PHP code, I can connect to the first server, but can't for the second:

```
$link = mssql_connect("10.201.74.50","hoteldw","password");
// mssql_get_last_message(): Changed database context to 'HotelDW'.
// Work

$link = mssql_connect("10.3.3.192\SQLEXPRESS,1433","p","password");
// mssql_get_last_message():
// string(73) "mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:  10.3.3.192\SQLEXPRESS,1433"

$link = mssql_connect("10.3.3.192\SQLEXPRESS","p","password"); 
// mssql_get_last_message():
// string(68) "mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:  10.3.3.192\SQLEXPRESS"

$link = mssql_connect("10.3.3.192,1433","p","password");
// mssql_get_last_message():
// string(62) "mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:  10.3.3.192,1433"
```

Comment: remove the port no from the second connection string. You either use `instance name` or `port no`

Comment: What version of `ntwdblib.dll` is on your PC and what does `mssql_get_last_message()` output?

Comment: @Squirrel, I tried it and there are same error. Please help to review my updated code above.

Comment: @Zhorov, ntwdblib.dll (Location: C:\Windows\SysWOW64, File version: 2000.80.194.0, Product name: Microsoft SQL Server, Product version: 8.00.194), mssql_get_last_message() is empty in case of Unable to connect to server. Please help to review my updated code above.

Comment: @Squirrel, I replaced the ntwdblib.dll file on php install folder from 7.00.839 to 8.00.2039 or higher version. It's working. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @Zhorov, I replaced the ntwdblib.dll file on php install folder from 7.00.839 to 8.00.2039 or higher version. It's working. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: [**Update your PHP!!!!!**](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) 5.2.6 is ancient and missing a LOT of extremely critical additions

Comment: OMG - you are still using sql server 2005! Do security and support matter at all?

Comment: @OMG, I'm not sure, because it's customer's server. However, they have plan to upgrade in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the ntwdblib.dll file on php install folder from 7.00.839 to 8.00.2039 or higher version.